# Will including the page number in the title of the articles in a series affect SEO?

Tags: seo, title

Let's say that we'll have an article series: **Python Tutorials**

Is it a good or bad choice to name articles like this?

1. **Python Tutorials - Part 1: Functions**
2. **Python Tutorials - Part 2: Understanding Object Oriented**
   ...
3. **Python Tutorials - Part 23: Test Driven Development in Python**

For readability, I believe it's good. When someone finds one of these articles from web, title says that you are in the middle of an article series.

How would this affect SEO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing a title for SEO, the unique and keyword rich parts of the title should come first.  Parts of the title that are the same across many pages or which don't contain keywords for which it would be good to rank should come at the end.  The following would be much more SEO friendly titles:

- Functions - Python Tutorials Part 1
- Understanding Object Oriented - Python Tutorials Part 2
- Test Driven Development in Python - Python Tutorials Part 23

This also makes sense for usability.  When a user has several parts of the tutorial open in different tabs, they need to be able to identify each tab.   Browsers usually only show 20 to 30 characters in each tab, so you want as much of the specific part of the tutorial to be identified early as possible.   Which your original titles, it would be very possible for a set of tabs to look like:

```
Python Tutorials - Par | Python Tutorials - Par | Python Tutorials - Par
```

With my titles, the tabs would look like:

```
Functions - Python Tut | Understanding Object O | Test Driven Developmen
```

The word "part" and the following number are not keywords for which you want to rank.   Using them in the title isn't going to help SEO at all.   It should be fine for SEO to have them in the title, but I'd make sure they come at the end.

You could also consider omitting the word "part" altogether:

- Functions - Python Tutorials 1
- Understanding Object Oriented - Python Tutorials 2
- Test Driven Development in Python - Python Tutorials 23

or abbreviating it like a page number:

- Functions - Python Tutorials p1
- Understanding Object Oriented - Python Tutorials p2
- Test Driven Development in Python - Python Tutorials p23

or showing the "out of 47" if there are 47 total parts to the tutorial:

- Functions - Python Tutorials 1/47
- Understanding Object Oriented - Python Tutorials 2/47
- Test Driven Development in Python - Python Tutorials 23/47

The other issue with your titles is that brand name can be very important in titles.   It could be very powerful to have the author or group that wrote the tutorials in the title.  Assuming you are the one writing these tutorials, you could use something like:

- Functions - Tolga's Python Tutorials p1
- Understanding Object Oriented - Tolga's Python Tutorials p2
- Test Driven Development in Python - Tolga's Python Tutorials p23

Doing so makes it a lot easier for people to search for this specific Python Tutorial.  It helps in 2 ways:

1. Search engines will be more likely to rank it for "Tolga's Python Tutorial."
2. Making the brand name prominent lets users know what they should be searching the next time they need to find it.